# Converting a function to typescript issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following function that I have tried to convert to typescript but run into issues:

```
import { Children, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface ChildType {
  role?: string;
}

export default function findChildrenByRole(
  children: ReactNode,
  role: string,
  limit: number | null = null,
) {
  const childrenArray = Children.toArray(children);

  const filteredChildren = childrenArray.filter(
    (child: ReactNode) => child?.type && (child.type as ChildType).role === role,
  );
  if (!filteredChildren.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return limit ? filteredChildren.slice(0, limit) : filteredChildren;
}
```

The issues can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Anyone know what I can do to fix this? Like the function works its just typescript being annoying :(

The function should basically take in children and then filter out those that have the role defined.
A child has a role defined by adding this line to the component: `Item.role = 'Child.Item';`

Comment: I tagged this with react (hope that's okay; if you don't think it depends on it, please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't refer to third-party libraries.)  Also, screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score -2):

ReactNode is basically anything that can be rendered inside your JSX. That's why TypeScript is saying that your Child may be boolean, string, null, or undefined(which won't have `role` property on them).

Instead of type-casting your `child.type`, you can add a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that filters out those other types.

Something like below:

```
interface ChildType {
  role?: string;
}

const isChildChildType = (child: ReactNode): child is Record<'type', ChildType> =>
  typeof child === 'function' &&
  'type' in child &&
  !!child.type &&
  typeof child.type === 'object' &&
  'role' in child.type;

export default function findChildrenByRole(children: ReactNode, role: string, limit: number | null = null) {
  const childrenArray = Children.toArray(children);

  const filteredChildren = childrenArray.filter((child: ReactNode) =>
    isChildChildType(child) ? child.type.role === role : false,
  );
  if (!filteredChildren.length) return null;

  return limit ? filteredChildren.slice(0, limit) : filteredChildren;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your solution in typescript playground? It has more errors than OP